# How do I use the Georgia font in PDFTeX?

Tags: fonts, pdftex

I can compile my LaTeX documents in LuaLaTeX with these lines in my preamble:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Georgia}
```

However, PDFLaTeX does not support `fontspec`, so this will not compile.

Is there any way to use the Georgia font (or a lookalike) that’s compatible with PDFLaTeX?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: You could try any of the fonts listed [on `tug.dk`](http://tug.dk/FontCatalogue/seriffontscategorised.html). The same designer also made Charter ([BT](http://tug.dk/FontCatalogue/charterbt) or [X](http://tug.dk/FontCatalogue/xcharter)). Or you could go for another wide serif font like any of the Garamonds listed there, of which I recommend [`garamondx`](http://tug.dk/FontCatalogue/garamondexpertmathdesign) (Install that [here](http://tug.org/fonts/getnonfreefonts).) If you need help choosing, will the document be read on a [screen or paper](//practicaltypography.com/system-fonts.html)?

Comment: [See also this newer question.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/464585/what-tips-and-tricks-should-i-know-when-using-the-georgia-font-in-latex/464586) This is a good question, but it narrowly asks only about PDFLaTeX (AKA the `latex` executable). Unless you’ve been using LaTeX for decades and know exactly how you like things, or unless someone ordered you to use PDFTeX, the modern toolchain is what you want for new documents. Especially with a TrueType font.

Answer (score 6):

If you need to support Georgia in math mode, or produce PostScript output (which the TrueType fonts `winfonts` supports do not have the right type of outlines for), the package you need is [`mathgifg`](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/mathgifg).

This package very much does not come with batteries included, for legal reasons.  You must even convert the TrueType files to Type 1 yourself.

An alternative is to load Georgia as your text font and some concordant math font (you might try `newpxmath` or `stix2`), then load `mathastext`.

Whether you use `winfonts` or `mathgifg`, I recommend you `\usepackage{microtype}` with font expansion on.  Some people don’t like it when printed out at high resolution, but it looks great on screen and cuts down on the number of hyphenated lines you need drastically.  Add the package option `[protrusion=false]` if you don’t like the hanging punctuation on the right margin.

#### PS

This answer has been significantly edited down, [following a discussion on the Meta site.](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7958/is-it-ok-to-change-an-ops-question-to-fit-an-answer/7960?noredirect=1#comment24713_7960)  I posted my original, much longer answer [as a separate question.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/464585/what-tips-and-tricks-should-i-know-when-using-the-georgia-font-in-latex/464586#464586)

Comment: The OP's question is just one year old. But note that the OP specifically asks for a solution in latex, and doesn't want to use xelatex or lualatex, so the line "There is a rudimentary package for this, `mathgifg`", would be sufficient to address the OP's question.

Comment: @Sverre To me the question seemed to be asking how to resolve the error message in LuaLaTeX on their system.

Comment: @Sverre I must have misread the date, however. Thanks for the correction!

Comment: Well, the OP's question is "Is there any way to use Georgia font [...] in only LaTex [Not LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX]?", so I think it's reasonably clear that (s)he is not asking about how to do this in lualatex.

Comment: Hey, LaTeX is the name of the kernel all three run. And if you specifically want something that does *not* compile on XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, we’d need to throw in an `\ifPDFLaTeX`.  But more seriously: I was motivated to come here because someone else wanted to know how to use Georgia in any TeX engine, and this was the answer that came up for her in her search engine. So, I wanted to give it a more useful answer and post for everyone. “I already got it working in LuaLaTeX, now how do I do it in PDFLaTeX” should not limit the answer.

Comment: @Sverre Actually, I’ll just edit the question if that’s a problem.

Comment: This issue should now be raised on the Meta site. I don't think it's appropriate within the StackExchange family to change an OP's question to fit the answer you would like to give, but that's for the community to decide. I can open a question about it on the Meta site.

Comment: Great and very detailed answer! But maybe it would be better to ask a new question and self-answer it with this answer instead of altering the question? Maybe we can change the title of this treat into "How to use Georgia with pdflatex" then your new question could have the more general title.

Comment: Please see [the question about this](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7958/is-it-ok-to-change-an-ops-question-to-fit-an-answer) on the meta site.

Answer (score 4):

The `winfonts` package has the necessary files to use the fonts which come with Windows XP , but you'll have to install it by yourself in your `texmf-local` tree. There's no math support, as far as I know.

To use `Georgia`, use a simple declaration:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\fontfamily{georgia}\selectfont
```

Comment: I am using Windows 10. Do I have to install any font package in windows before I use the code you provided?

Comment: Yes: `winfonts` is not part of any distribution (for licensing reasons, I guess), albeit you find it on CTAN. There's a detailed documentation with the package.